# Mathematica is acting as though d is a variable when it isn't

Tags: syntax

I have the Airy Stress Function

```
ϕ[x_, y_] = 
  1/120 (P/(d^3))[5*(x^3 - x*L^2)*(y + d)^2*(y - 2*d) - 3*x*y*(y^2 - d^2)^2]
```

That I need to take 2nd and 4th derivatives of. P, L, and d are constants (a force, length, and height). When I give Mathematica the command:

```
σ[x_, y_] = D[ϕ[x, y], y, y]
```

which should take two partial derivatives with respect to y (all else constant), it returns

```
1/120 (-24 x y^3 + 10 (-L^2 x + x^3) (-2 d + y) + 
    20 (-L^2 x + x^3) (d + y) - 36 x y (-d^2 + y^2)) Derivative[
   1][(1/d^3)][
   5 (-L^2 x + x^3) (-2 d + y) (d + y)^2 - 3 x y (-d^2 + y^2)^2] + 
 1/120 (10 (-L^2 x + x^3) (-2 d + y) (d + y) + 
    5 (-L^2 x + x^3) (d + y)^2 - 12 x y^2 (-d^2 + y^2) - 
    3 x (-d^2 + y^2)^2)^2 ((1/d^3)^\[Prime]\[Prime])[
   5 (-L^2 x + x^3) (-2 d + y) (d + y)^2 - 3 x y (-d^2 + y^2)^2]
```

While I expect the derivative to be messy, the primes around the 1/d^3 factors means the D[] function isn't operating as expected, and mathematica wants to take derivatives of d. What is going wrong here?

Comment: `(P/(d^3))[5*(x^3 - x*L^2)*(y + d)^2*(y - 2*d) - 3*x*y*(y^2 - d^2)^2]` Note that `[...]` defines the argument of a function -- in this case, the argument of the "function" `(P/(d^3))`. Changing those square brackets to parentheses should fix this issue.

Comment: You are a life saver! Thanks a million.